# C++98: Provide different function implementations, depending on the existance of a member

Tags: c++, templates, macros, member

**Setup:** There is a class `classA`, and a class `classB` that is using `classA`. Unfortunately, when programming `classB`, I do not know whether `classA` will have a certain member `someMember` or not. Depending on that, a member function `someFunction` in `classB` shall be implemented either the one or the other way. As the one way is using `someMember`, it is *important that this function instance is not compiled in the case `someMember` is not a member of `classA`*.

**Question:** Apart from macros/defines, what is the best solution for that in C++98?

**MWE:**

```
class classA
{
public:
    // c'tor
    classA()
    {
        //someMember = 3;
    };
    // does not have the member "someMember"
    //int someMember;
};

class classB
{
public:
    // only compile this function if "someMember" is a member of classB
    int someFunction(classA a)
    {
        return a.someMember;
    }
    // ...and compile this one otherwise
    int someFunction(classA a)
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

// --- just to have an MWE: ---
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    classA a;
    classB b;
    cout << b.someFunction(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I do not know whether classA will have a certain member someMember or not" do you mean that `classB` is a template in your real code and `classA` is a template parameter?

Comment: No, that means there exist different versions of `classA`, and depending on which version of `classA` I am using it will have `someMember` or not. This is a compatibility and configuration issue. `classA` lives in a different software component that could be combined in different versions with my (`classB`'s) software component.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector

Comment: You're going to have to explain a little why " you can't know" class `A` will have `someMember` or not. Is someone else developing that class, and won't tell you?

Comment: @Spencer: He would tell me, but his `classA` exists, e.g., in a version 1 (without member) and a version 2 (with member). As I know my `classB` can be used with both versions, and I don't want to branch my software component, I want `classB` to automatically work in both cases (by switching the implementation of `someFunction`).

Comment: @acraig5075 Thanks :) That looks useful. I will give it a try!

Comment: @Matheburg could you get him to add a static const version number?  That would give you something to base a template off of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question is tagged `templates` I assume your `classB` can actually be a class template or at least it can use one... If this is the case you could apply [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) e.g. using following solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class classA
{
public:
    // c'tor
    classA()
    {
        someMember = 3;
    };
    // does not have the member "someMember"
    int someMember;
};

template<class T, class = void>
class classB_impl
{
public:
    // ...and compile this one otherwise
    int someFunction(T)
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

template <class T>
class classB_impl<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().someMember, void())> {
public:
    // only compile this function if "someMember" is a member of classB
    int someFunction(T a)
    {
        return a.someMember;
    }
};

using classB = classB_impl<classA>;

int main() {
   classB b;
   std::cout << b.someFunction(classA{}) << std::endl;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QK2HwbuN2hnSlIDk)

---

In this case (if you are using c++98) you might get more lucky trying to use additional trait e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

class classA
{
public:
    // c'tor
    classA()
    {
        someMember = 3;
    };
    // does not have the member "someMember"
    int someMember;
};

template <class T, int T::*V = &T::someMember>
struct someMemberTrait {
    typedef void type;
};

template<class T, class = void>
class classB_impl
{
public:
    // ...and compile this one otherwise
    int someFunction(T)
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

template <class T>
class classB_impl<T, typename someMemberTrait<T>::type> {
public:
    // only compile this function if "someMember" is a member of classB
    int someFunction(T a)
    {
        return a.someMember;
    }
};

typedef classB_impl<classA> classB;

int main() {
   classB b;
   std::cout << b.someFunction(classA()) << std::endl;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HUhoJjItSdT4yAmR)

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Unfortunately, you won't believe it, we are still using C++98 standard. As far as I know `decltype` is not available there.